# MySQL repeating events monthly/yearly

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm working on repeating events that can occur every 1/2/3/4/5 or 6 months/years. I found some solutions here but they are mostly for days/weeks.

Also I must get events that are 15 days before due time. Script will run each day at midnight and check if there are events (reminders) that are due to 15 days and send notification (insert into table).

Here is the query I tried.

```
SELECT *, ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, first_date - INTERVAL 15 DAY, CURDATE())) AS diff, 
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, first_date, first_date + INTERVAL `repeat` * IF(repeat_type = '0', 1, 12) MONTH) AS tdiff FROM reminders
WHERE 
ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, first_date - INTERVAL 15 DAY, CURDATE())) % 
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, first_date, first_date + INTERVAL `repeat` * IF(repeat_type = '0', 1, 12) MONTH) = 0
OR ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, first_date, CURDATE())) = 0;
```

The `repeat_type` determines if reminder occurs monthly or yearly (0 = monthly, 1 = yearly). The `repeat` attribute is quantity (1-6).

I think the problem is with difference (2nd `TIMESTAMPDIFF`). It calculates difference between two dates and returns number of seconds. However, months aren't equal (28-31 days) and because of that modulo (%) sometimes doesn't return zero. I was thinking I can handle this with some kind of range (modulo has to return 0 or <= 3 days) but I'm not sure what values would be appropriate.

Today is 12 September 2018 (2018-09-12). I've added a couple of rows in table that are due to 2018-09-27, that's 15 days from today.
When I run above query (without `where` clause) I get this:

```
+----+------+------------+--------+-------------+---------+----------+----------+
| id | type | first_date | repeat | repeat_type | message | diff     | tdiff    |
+----+------+------------+--------+-------------+---------+----------+----------+
| 19 | 0    | 2018-09-27 |      6 | 0           | A       |        0 | 15638400 |
| 20 | 1    | 2018-09-27 |      1 | 1           | AA      |        0 | 31536000 |
| 21 | 2    | 2018-09-27 |      1 | 1           | AAA     |        0 | 31536000 |
| 22 | 3    | 2018-09-27 |      0 | 1           | AAAA    |        0 |        0 |
| 23 | 1    | 2018-03-27 |      2 | 0           | OPA     | 15897600 |  5270400 |
+----+------+------------+--------+-------------+---------+----------+----------+
```

If you look at the last row (Repeat every two months starting from 2018-03-27), it should be in the results with `where` clause.
But 15897600 % 5270400=86400 (that's one day).

Comment: Why don't you try crone jobs?

Comment: @umarbilal yes, I will use them but this query will run in that cron job.

Comment: @ThomasG what's the difference?

Comment: Add one month to 2018-08-31, which date do you expect in your logic (not the computer logic)? First october or 30th september?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Run it daily.  First, check to see if it is the first of the month; die if it is not.